# Debugging Python in VS Code in Windows

Tags: python, bash, debugging, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have VS Code installed on my Windows machine with the Python extension.  I have also installed Windows Sub-system for Linux (Ubuntu) so I have the Bash shell available. I am experimenting with combining VS Code on Windows.  In VS Code, I have set my default terminal to Bash (WSL.exe).  The code is very simple for testing:

```
msg = "Hello World"
pring(msg)
```

I set my breakpoint on the second line so that I can see code executing.  When I launch the debugger however, the debugger does not work.  Here is the output in the terminal:

```
bruparel@WIN-XPI7AFTJ1F:/mnt/c/Users/bharat.c.ruparel/py_work$ cd c:\Users\bharat.c.ruparel\py_work && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && set "PYTHONPATH=c:\Users\bharat.c.ruparel\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.8.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd" && C:\Users\bharat.c.ruparel\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe -m ptvsd --host localhost --port 58124 c:\Users\bharat.c.ruparel\py_work\hello_world.py "
-bash: cd: c:Usersbharat.c.ruparelpy_work: No such file or directory
```

As you can see above, Bash is having trouble concatenating the path.  When I switch my default terminal to the either the PowerShell or DOS, the debugger launches correctly.

I am more used to the Bash prompt having used Mac and Linux for a long time.  Now that I have to use Windows, I was trying to combine VS Code on windows side to use the Linux Subsystems's Bash shell.

The debugger has stopped me however.  Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: from the windows subsystem for linux, you access the C: drive of the windows machine at `/mnt/c` not `c:\Users`

Comment: I know that.  My question is how do I make adjustments to VS Code debugger settings so that it is the Python from Linux side that executes/launches my debugging code.  I have identical versions of Anaconda installed both on Windows subsystem for linux side and windows side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python extension for VS Code [does not support WSL yet](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/67).